# Can the player choose a different player as a target?

Tags: twilight-imperium, twilight-imperium-3rd-edition

In a Twilight Imperium (3rd edition) game, when the "Checks and balances (LAW)" card is in play, which states

> When a player chooses a Strategy Card during the Strategy Phase, he must give the chosen card to another player (who does not currently have a Strategy Card).

And if somebody then uses the Action Card "Public Disgrace", which says

> After a player has chosen a Strategy Card, play this card to force the player to return that Strategy Card and choose a different one.

The question is: can the player then use a different target for the new Strategy Card, or should the target stay the same and would he get the next card too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find any rules that back up this specific situation but this is my interpretation. The trigger for the LAW states:

> When a player chooses a Strategy Card...

So if someone were to play an action card which forces that player to put their current strategy card back and choose a different strategy card, the LAW would trigger again allowing the player to choose the same person to give the strategy card to or a different person.